Forks of algebras over monads in proof of Beck's criterion
Consider a monad $T=(T,\mu,\eta)$  and a $T$-algebra $(X,\xi).$ Then lots of expositions of Beck's monadicity criterion refer to the following fact: there is a parallel pair of morphisms of $T$-algebras $$\mu_X,T\xi: (T^2X,\mu_{TX})\to (TX,\mu_X),$$ its coequalizer is $(X,\xi)$, and after forgetting the $T$-algebra structure it becomes a split fork with the splitting morphisms $\eta_X$ and $\eta_{TX}$, i.e. we have

$\xi\circ\eta_X=1$
$\mu_X\circ\eta_{TX}=1$
$T\xi\circ \eta_{TX}=\eta_X\circ\xi$

This is supposed to be elementary, and I couldn't find a single source where this is checked explicitly. It probably really is elementary, but I have by now spent multiple hours trying to establish that $T\xi$ is actually a morphism of $T$-algebras and the last equality $T\xi\circ \eta_{TX}=\eta_X\circ\xi$. How can one see this?
What annoys me the most is that both of the statements I am struggling with are obvious in the context of monoids and their actions, and yet I still can't seem to generalize this to the case of monads. Is there perhaps to think of monads as monoids in the category of endofunctors and, similar to using the Yoneda embedding, completely reduce such arguments to arguments about monoids?

I shouldn't comment without thinking through, but... the equation you write really seems naturality of $\eta$: $Tf\circ \eta_A = \eta_B\circ f$ for every $f : A\to B$.

Ditto for "$T\xi$ is a morphism of algebras": seems the same property of "$\mu$ is natural at $T\xi$". (I say seems because I'm sleepy and didn't really do more than scribbling naturality squares. And if it really was that simple, I'm glad to have solved your issue.)

@fosco You are absolutely right. In fact, I was sure it was something obvious like this. I think at some point long ago when learning monads I made a mistake of treating $\xi$ as not a morphism $TX\to X$, but a component of a natural transformation $T\to 1$, and later on overcompensated by treating all components of natural transformations of functors as just morphisms. Thank you!

Heh! Happens all the time, don't be hard on yourself :) when I started I made a similar mistake in reading the definition, fortunately I was corrected in due time!
